# exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java .net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

Tags: java, rmi, rpc, corba, access-denied

i am trying to execute sample RMI APPLICATION with following code

---

```
/* DemoInterface.java*/ //STEP-1  
//Create the remote interface  
import java.rmi.Remote;   
import java.rmi.RemoteException;   
public interface DemoInterface extends Remote  
{  
    public String SayDemo() throws RemoteException;  

}
```

---

```
    import java.rmi.Naming;
    import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
    import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
    public class DemoClient 
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
            {
                System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
            }
            try
            {
                Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(args[0]);      
                DemoInterface h = (DemoInterface) reg.lookup("f1");
                System.out.println (h.SayDemo());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println ("DemoClient exception: " + e);
            }
        }
    }  


----------

import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public class DemoServer implements DemoInterface
{
    private String message;
    public DemoServer() 
    {
           super();
    }
    public DemoServer(String msg) throws RemoteException
    {
        message = msg;
    }
    public String SayDemo() throws RemoteException
    {
        return message;
    }
    public static void main (String[] argv) 
    {
        try
        {   DemoInterface h = new DemoServer("Advance jAVA");
            DemoInterface stub = (DemoInterface)   UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(h, 0);
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            reg.rebind ("f1", stub);
            //System.out.println ("Server is connected and ready for  operation.");
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println("Server not connected: " + e);
        }
    } 
}
```

---

### client.policy

```
grant codeBase "file:/RMI/DemoWorld/"
{
    permission javsecurity.AllPermission;
};
```

---

### server.policy

```
grant codeBase "file:/RMI/DemoWorld/"
{
    permission javsecurity.AllPermission;
};
```

to run application i follow below given step

1. -start rmiregistry
2. java -cp D:\RMI\DemoWorld; Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/D/RMI/DemoWorld/
   -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Djava.security.policy=server.policy DemoServer
3. java -cp D:\RMI\DemoWorld;
   -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/RMI/DemoWorld/ -Djava.security.policy=client.policy DemoClient 127.0.0.1
   but i got following error

DemoClient exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java
.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

Comment: Run your client with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure` to see what is going on. Most likely your .policy file isn't being loaded, or else the codebase you're running from isn't what you think it is, but this output will tell you.

Comment: Looks like a typo in your policy files.

Comment: i dont understand what do you say? would you please explain in detail

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? What happened when you followed my suggestion?